# Batch file to delete files older than; except for files with xxxx* in the filename

Tags: batch-file

I have made a batch file to robocopy /MOVE files with xxxx* in the file name to a temp folder, then a second command using forfiles to delete any files in the original directory older than -xx days old, then using the robocopy /move to move all the other files back to the original directory. Is there a way I can run the forfiles command to delete all files older than -xx days EXCEPT files with xxxx* in the name from the original director without moving files back and forth?

My original code is:

```
forfiles -p "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Media\TV" -s -m . -d -45 -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

Comment: I would think you could echo the file name and pipe it to the `FINDSTR` command to do a reverse find on files that begin with `xxxxx`. Then use conditional execution to delete the file.

Comment: Updates to code should go in your question. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Please learn, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is the option `-m .` intended for? Anyway, Why not staying with robocopy, perhaps also with its `/XF xxxx*` option?

Comment: @aschipfl good call. Totally forgot about the exclude option with `ROBOCOPY'.

Comment: I am moving away from robocopy all together as the files are linked to a program, making it unstable, even though I kill task before copy. I would rather just delete the no longer needed files. Also the files are large media files, so adds time to my cleanup process.. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using `FORFILES` with some added help of the `FOR` and `FINDSTR` commands.  But I believe you could do this all with ROBOCOPY if you wanted to .

```
FORFILES /S /D -45 /C "cmd /q /c FOR /F %%G IN (@file) do echo %%~G|findstr /v /b xxxx >nul && del @path"
```